# Visual Studio IDE RpcIpcMessagePortClosedError: Cannot send the message - the message port has been closed for the process 18182

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, aws-amplify

How to fix
RpcIpcMessagePortClosedError: Cannot send the message - the message port has been closed for the process 18182.
i am using vscode and nodejs amplify.

I run the ui code with npm start. Normally the site should be open. I am using react and nodejs with TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the maximum number of file watchers limits exceeded on your system.

**If you try to run many applications at a same time, this problem occurs.**

*To solve the issue on Linux based operating system execute the following command in terminal,*

```
//for Debian, RedHat and other similar Linux distros
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

//for ArchLinux
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/40-max-user-watches.conf && sudo sysctl --system
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by closing the visual studio code windows that I used to examine other project code. It worked then, but I think it might be that Visual Studio Code can't keep track of project dependencies for the project it runs when there are a few windows and projects. But I'm not sure. That solved my problem. I've encountered the same problem before. Can someone satisfy my curiosity about this? Is this caused by visual studio code? Does anyone really have an idea if this is the cause of the problem?